# Year condition works fine but i run with year and date its shows null

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
SELECT Sum(gross_motor + visual_motor_skills 
       + draws_a_person + prints_personal_data) 
FROM   brigance_screening_term0 AS T0 
WHERE  year = 2011 
   AND Str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d') = 2016 - 05 - 11 
LIMIT  1
```

Comment: post example too, change this `2016 - 05 - 11` to `'2016-5-11'`. Remove extra spaces

Comment: SELECT Sum(gross_motor + visual_motor_skills 
       + draws_a_person + prints_personal_data) 
FROM   brigance_screening_term0 AS T0 
WHERE  year = 2011 
LIMIT  1  Its show the result

Comment: SELECT Sum(gross_motor + visual_motor_skills 
       + draws_a_person + prints_personal_data) 
FROM   brigance_screening_term0 AS T0 
WHERE  year = 2011 
   AND Str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d') = 2016 - 05 - 11 
LIMIT  1  Its shows null

Answer (score 0):

seem you have a typo

```
 AND Str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d') = 2016 - 05 - 11
```

should be

```
 AND Str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-05-11'
```